# Using gulp.watch with browserified karma/jasmine unit tests fails on error

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, gulp, browserify, gulp-watch

I'm running into [this error with gulp.watch](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/627). Essentially, when a test unit fails with an error, then the watch command hangs--i.e. runs exactly once and then watch does not trigger events again.

The prescribed workaround is to use [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-plumber) to prevent exit on errors. However, this only works with streams. If I'm running karma tests together with browserify, my configuration looks similar to this (and I can't determine how to hook streams into this bad boy to enable plumber):

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['test']);
  gulp.watch('test/**/*.spec.js', ['test']);
});

gulp.task('test', function () {
  return karma.server.start({
    files: [
      'test/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],
    preprocessors: {
      'test/**/*.spec.js': ['coverage', 'browserify']
    },
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    reporters: ['coverage', 'spec', 'failed'],
    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: ['browserify-istanbul']
    },
    singleRun: true
  });
});
```

Does anyone have a workaround for running test units with watch or recommendations on how I could get this to work with gulp-plumber?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution here was to remove gulp.watch from the picture. Since browserify is being used as a preprocessor, Karma's internal watching works magically with no need for watchify or gulp.watch.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  return karma.server.start({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
  });
});

gulp.task('test', function () {
  return karma.server.start({
    configFile: __dirname+'/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  });
});
```

And my adjusted config file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      'test/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],
    preprocessors: {
      'test/**/*.spec.js': ['coverage', 'browserify']
    },
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    reporters: ['coverage', 'spec', 'failed'],
    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: ['browserify-istanbul']
    }
  });
};
```